# unable to connect to my DB

Tags: java, mysql, database

I am getting this error when I try compiling

```
ConnectDB.java:14: error: unreported exception ClassNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class ConnectDB
{
   public ConnectDB() throws SQLException
   {
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      Connection dbConnect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:3306/my_DB", "userName", "superSecurePassword");
   }
}
```

I have downloaded and installed the driver and set the classpath but continue to get the error.

Answer (score 4):

That's because *the compiler* is telling you that you're not catching a checked exception. You need appropriate handling:

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
} catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // log exception, probably abort application if it can't run without a database
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to place the following code

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
```

inside a **try catch block**. Because the code **throws** **checked exception** and compiler force to **catch** the **checked exception**.